# How can I enforce a void method to return Void from a Stub object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

How can I enforce a stub object in RhinoMocks to return void for a void method on it?

Take this example:

```
public interface ICar 
{
    string Model {get;set;}
    void Horn();
}

ICar stubCar= MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICar>();
stubCar.Expect(c=>c.Horn()).Return( //now what so that 
                                   // it returns nothing as the meth. returns void ?
```

Comment: If it's defined with a void return type, how _could_ it return anything?

Comment: My concern was if I do not enforce it to return void, the call to this stub will throw an exception. I tried and saw that: Jon was right!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method *can't* return a value - it's a void method. The CLR won't *let* it try to return a value. You don't need to test for this.

You only need the `Expect` call.

Answer (score 6):

The `Return()` method is invalid for a void method call. Rather you want something like this:

```
ICar stubCar= MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<ICar>();
stubCar.Expect(c=>c.Horn());
stubCar.DoSomethingThatIsSupposedToCallHorn();
stubCar.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

which will tell you whether or not `Horn()` was called.

That's how you test that void methods are called when unit testing. You do the following:

1. Set up an Expectation (`Expect()`)
2. Call the method that should invoke the expectation
3. Verify that the expected method was called.

Comment: I dont think this will work because you are using a Stub not a Mock, and stubs will always pass VerifyAllExpectations

see: http://www.wrightfully.com/on-rhino-mocks-verifyallexpectations-vs-assertwascalled/

Comment: That should be a strict mock. I'll change it. Thanks for catching that.